# Cron help! Bi monthly jobs isn't working

Tags: linux, scripting, cron

I have a cronjob to back up some things, and it doesn't seem to be working.  You can see here it is set for 0:00 on the 1st of every other month, it should have ran this morning.

```
0 0 1 1/2 * ./gitbackup.sh
```

Here is the log - it isn't running!?

```
Aug 31 23:17:01 git-us CRON[22871]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug 31 23:20:01 git-us CRON[23349]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Aug 31 23:40:02 git-us CRON[26562]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Sep  1 00:00:01 git-us CRON[29878]: (smmsp) CMD (test -x /etc/init.d/sendmail && /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail cron-msp)
Sep  1 00:00:01 git-us CRON[29879]: (bind) CMD ( /usr/sbin/ldap2bind)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because I was running from the wrong path....doh!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Cron manual, to specify every other month you want:

```
0 0 1 */2 * ./gitbackup.sh
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
0 0 1 2,4,6,8,10,12 * ./gitbackup.sh
```

The advantage of the second form is that you can choose even or odd months, and your intent is clear to the reader.

Comment: I'll give it a try and send it for 2nd of month so we will know tomorrow.